# How can I make my Unity 2d scene pitch black, except for manually added lighting?

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting

I have tried modifying all the settings suggested that I can find, but the lighting of objects in my Scene remains unchanged. I've used the "Generate" button, I've set "Intensity Multiple" to 0, I've enabled/disable Scene lighting, I've set the Environment Lighting to black, there are no lights in the Light Explorer, etc.

I want everything but the Canvas HUD to be completely black, except anything illuminated by manually added lights. Is there some way to do this in the latest Unity that I'm somehow missing?

**Edit 2:** I have changed the material of my sprites, and now there is total darkness, except when I place lights. I changed the Rendering Mode of the material to Fade to fix the HUD being blocked from viewing by the tiles, and now the problem is that a light placed as a child of the player is causing the player to appear as a purely black version of his sprite.

Comment: What content do you have in your scene right now that's receiving lighting? Can you show us a sample?

Comment: All of it. The best I could get for reducing lighting was a black skybox behind all the backgrounds, tiles, and objects.

Comment: "All of it" helps someone who has seen your scene and knows what's in it. Unfortunately, we're not in that position, so you'll need to specifically list what kinds of renderers, materials, shaders, etc you've placed into your scene.

Comment: It's a 2d scene, and I have not explicitly added any materials or shaders, nor renderers besides the default (i.e. Sprites-default material). I'm not sure what other facts are relevant here, since everything else I have is the basic 2d-platformer stuff.

Comment: The default sprite material is unlit - it always displays the native brightness/colour of the texture, regardless of lights in the scene. Did you mean to use a lit material or the 2D lighting system to handle darkening/shadowing your sprites?

Comment: I suppose I did, I didn't know that's how that works. Creating a new material and leaving as is, and then applying it to objects in my scene is giving me what I want, except the player character has become a black rectangle (it is the object with the light component on it currently)

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to show us how you've set up your scene content so far, and how the appearance differs from what you want.

Comment: You have not given us enough information about your setup for us to reproduce this problem in a new empty project. Please edit your question to walk us through every single step to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. When the way you've done it isn't working, it's a good sign that other people don't do it that way, so you should be explicit about the details of how you've chosen to do it.

Comment: For instance, you did not tell us *where* you placed the light relative to the player object. Did you place it in front of the player (closer to the camera) so the light has room to shine onto the player's surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default rendering material (formally called a Material, set in the Sprite Renderer component) for sprites is automatically fully visible regardless of other lights in the scene. In order to have a sprite affected by light (or the lack thereof), one must change the material to a different one. Setting to a newly created Material with all default settings suffices to make sprites respond to light. One should set "Intensity Multiple" to 0 and the Environment Lighting color to black, then press the "Generate" button, in order to actually remove the ambient light.

The Z position of the light, and the particular settings of the material, may affect how things actually end up getting lit, assuming one is using the default renderer with 3D Lights (just called Lights in the menus). The Rendering Mode of the material affects the results, with Fade being the option that solved some of my problems.

Comment: "One should set "Intensity Multiple" to 0 and the Environment Lighting color to black, then press the "Generate" button, in order to actually remove the ambient light" no, you should probably turn off baked global illumination if you're not using it, rather than paying the overhead of generating and storing unused lighting information and lighting everything with a pure black baked light.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as "Accepted" if it worked for you.